# ¿Cómo hacer que una línea de código inicie después de 5 segundos en Java?

Tags: java

En mi programa tengo varios `if`, y quiero que haya un intervalo de 5 segundos en la ejecución de estos.

Ejemplo:

```
if(){
}

5 segundos

if(){
}
```

Comment: Pones en Google como hacer un timeout en Java y te sale

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow. Puede mirar `Thread.sleep` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html .Saludos

Comment: @Javi enserio?.

Comment: Hay que ser un poco autodidacta!

Answer (score 6):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
         try {
            //Ponemos a "Dormir" el programa durante los ms que queremos
            Thread.sleep(5*1000);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
         }
```

La función Thread.sleep() se utiliza para detener la ejecución de un hilo durante una cantidad de tiempo especificada en ms, al ser una función de la clase Thread, debe ir acompañada del bloque try-catch para manejar las posibles excepciones que pueden llegarse a producir.

Comment: Por favor incluye algún tipo de explicación del código. De lo contrario, resulta poco útil como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos formas de hacerlo como te respondieron mas arriba la primera es utilizar un Thread (Hilo) de la siguiente forma :

```
try {
       //Ponemos a "Dormir" el programa durante los ms que queremos
   Thread.sleep(5*1000);
}
catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

la otra forma es utilizar un hilo pero con un Executor Service al cual le especificas un delay y un intervalo para ejecutar una tarea :

```
public static void scheduleDelayTask1()
{
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Runnable task1 = () -> System.out.println("Saludos a StackOverFlow");
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 2, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //scheduleWithFixedDelay es aconsejable usarlo cuando no importa que se siga un patron de tiempo, distinto a scheduleFixedRate que se ejecuta cronologicamente siempre
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya te han constestado, pero en ocasiones, la solución no sabemos aplicarla. Soy partidario de generar métodos para cierta funcionalidad, por tanto no te vendría mal este ejemplo.

```
public class TuClase{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("inicia programa");

        esperar(3);

        if(1 > 0){
            System.out.println("Algo");
        }

        esperar(5);

        if(true){
            System.out.println("Otra cosa");
        }

        esperar(2);

        System.out.println("Fin de programa");      
    }

    /**
     * Pausa la ejecución durante X segundos.
     * @param segundos El número de segundos que se quiere esperar.
     */
    public static void esperar(int segundos){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(segundos * 1000);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
         }
    }   

}
```